# What law(s) did Paul Bussetti break when he burnt the model of Grenfell Tower?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom

Paul Bussetti has just been given a [10-week suspended jail sentence](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-61160971) for burning a model of [Grenfell Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenfell_Tower_fire) (The tower in London that caught fire in 2017 killing 72 people).

Having read that BBC article and some others (Guardian, LBC) no one has said what law(s) he broke.

What law(s) has he broken?

Comment: Related news article about an earlier trial (linked at the bottom of your article) says *Mr Bussetti, of South Norwood, was accused of sending "grossly offensive" material via a public communications network.*

Comment: @CaiusJard ah thank you, `sending "grossly offensive" material` lead me to this https://www.jmw.co.uk/services-for-business/business-crime/malicious-communications-act-offences#:~:text=Offences%20that%20fall%20under%20section,or%20content%20to%20be%20sent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first sentence of the cited article reads:

> A man has admitted sharing a **grossly offensive** video of a cardboard model of Grenfell Tower being burned on a bonfire.

[Section 127](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/21/section/127?timeline=false) of the Communications Act 2003 seems to be the most relevant offence:

> (1)A person is guilty of an offence if he—
>
> (a)sends by means of a public electronic communications network a message or other matter that is grossly offensive...

However, there's also similar offence under [section 1](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/27/section/1?timeline=false) of the Malicious Communications Act 1988:

> (1)Any person who sends to another person—
>
> (a)a letter, electronic communication or article of any description which conveys—
>
> - (i)a message which is indecent or grossly offensive;
>
> (b) [...]
>
> is guilty of an offence if his purpose, or one of his purposes, in sending it is that it should, so far as falling within paragraph (a) or (b) above, cause distress or anxiety to the recipient or to any other person to whom he intends that it or its contents or nature should be communicated...

Both charges seem available on the information provided, so it was up to the Crown Prosecution Service to pick the most likely to succeed.

Comment: "it was up to the Crown Prosecution Service to pick the most likely to succeed": Is it not the CPS's duty to prosecute both crimes and leave the rest to the court?

Comment: @phoog Not when the sentence for the easer to prove crime is at least as large.

Comment: @phoog it’s up to the CP to choose whether to prosecute none, either, or both

Comment: @phoog According to the mainstream media there's only one offence (ie one actus reus), but it falls under two seperate pieces of legislation each with their own points to prove and maximum sentencing provisions.  The CPS might've laid them as alternative charges on the indictment, but he could only be convicted for one, not both. It's like convicting someone of murder, manslaughter, assault, and battery for a single death (but things may be different in the USA).